# Java use Enum based on Manufacturer

Tags: java, enums

I wanted to have two Enums, the first should hold all Car Manufacturers and the second all Models of each Manufacturer. Due to size limitations I created an Enum for every Manufacturer, like so `CarManufacturer`,`ModelsBMW`.

Now I want to use a the Model based on the Manufacturer.

```java
public enum CarManufacturer {
  BMW,
  Audi;

  public CarModels getModel(CarManufacturer i){
    switch(i.name()){
      case "BMW":
        return ModelsBMW;
      break;
     case "Audi":
        return ModelsAudi;
      break;
    }
  }
}

public enum ModelsBMW {
  M1("M1");
  //... more BMW models
}
```

There will be more manufacturer and models added and removed.
Is there a way to choose the right Enum in getModel() without writing every case?

Comment: Is your code compiling? We can't do "return ModelsBMW;". It should be some specific value from the enum rather.

Comment: Do you need to return all the enums?

Comment: No it was just pseudo code. It should be possible to return all models of a manufacturer

Comment: Check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enum` as below to avoid switch cases:

**Enum Code:**

```
enum CarManufacturer {
  BMW(ModelsBMW::values), Audi(ModelsAudi::values);

  private Supplier<CarModels[]> objectCreator;

  CarManufacturer(final Supplier<CarModels[]> objectCreator) {
    this.objectCreator = objectCreator;
  }

  public CarModels[] getModels() {
    return objectCreator.get();
  }
}
```

**Basic Related Code for Successful Code Build:**

```
interface CarModels {

}

enum ModelsBMW implements CarModels {
  M1("M1");

  private String model;

  private ModelsBMW(String model) {
    this.model = model;
  }
}

enum ModelsAudi implements CarModels {
  A1("A1");

  private String model;

  private ModelsAudi(String model) {
    this.model = model;
  }
}
```

Here `getModels` method will provide you all the models related to specific manufacturer.